# Python - Passing functions to other functions

Tags: python, function

I'm having problems passing `crapsRoll()` to `gameCraps()`. When I define `gameCraps()` I get the error:

> Redefining name 'crapsRoll' from outer scope.

And on the print statement I get an error that says

> crapsRoll has no value.

```
import random 

#===========================crapsRoll()===============================
def crapsRoll():
  roll = random.randint(2,12)
  return(roll)

#===========================gameCraps()===============================
def gameCraps(crapsRoll):
  crapsRoll = crapsRoll
  if (crapsRoll == 7 or crapsRoll == 11):
    gameState = 1
  elif (crapsRoll == 2 or crapsRoll == 3 or crapsRoll == 12):
    gameState = 2
  else:
    gameState = 3
  return(gameState)

print(gameCraps())
```

Comment: Do you like crap so much you named 2 functions after it?

Comment: @cᴏʟᴅsᴘᴇᴇᴅ crapS <-- with an 's' ?

Answer (score 2):

You don't need to pass it as a argument. Just call it from another function:

```
def gameCraps():
  crapsRoll = crapsRoll()
  if (crapsRoll == 7 or crapsRoll == 11):
    gameState = 1
  elif (crapsRoll == 2 or crapsRoll == 3 or crapsRoll == 12):
    gameState = 2
  else:
    gameState = 3
  return(gameState)
```

Comment: This overwrites the function name with the local variable, probably not a good idea

Comment: also it doesnt answer the users question, as it doesnt pass the function as an argument.

Answer (score 1):

If you insist on keeping this structure, this will work:

```
import random 

#===========================crapsRoll()===============================
def crapsRoll():
  roll = random.randint(2,12)
  return(roll)

#===========================gameCraps()===============================
def gameCraps(crapsRoll):
  crapsRoll = crapsRoll
  if (crapsRoll == 7 or crapsRoll == 11):
    gameState = 1
  elif (crapsRoll == 2 or crapsRoll == 3 or crapsRoll == 12):
    gameState = 2
  else:
    gameState = 3
  return(gameState)

print(gameCraps(crapsRoll()))
```

You either have to pass the return value of `crapsRoll()` to `gameCraps(<insert int>)` or call `crapsRoll()` from within `gameCraps()`, as all functions are registered in the same namespace. I don't know the structure of your code, but I would rather refactor it, than creating such a [trainwreck](http://wiki.c2.com/?TrainWreck). This is not ment in a bad manner :).

Comment: we can definitely pass functions in python as an argument

Comment: Updated the answer accordingly. Thanks!

Comment: this doesnt answer the users question, as it doesnt pass the function as an argument, just the result

Answer (score 0):

```
#===========================gameCraps()===============================
def gameCraps(crapsRoll):
  print crapsRoll
  if (crapsRoll == 7 or crapsRoll == 11):
    gameState = 1
  elif (crapsRoll == 2 or crapsRoll == 3 or crapsRoll == 12):
    gameState = 2
  else:
    gameState = 3
  return(gameState)

print(gameCraps(crapsRoll()))
```

This can be done in multiple ways, but calling function just one time will be feasible

Answer (score 0):

You are trying to check whether the function has a value of a number, which it doesnt, you need to call the function to get the result.

To summarize from what I believe are two nearly complete answers:

```
import random 

#===========================crapsRoll()===============================
def crapsRoll():
  roll = random.randint(2,12)
  return(roll)

#===========================gameCraps()===============================
def gameCraps(rollFunction):
  crapsRollResult = rollFunction()
  if (crapsRollResult  == 7 or crapsRollResult  == 11):
    gameState = 1
  elif (crapsRollResult  == 2 or crapsRollResult  == 3 or crapsRollResult  == 12):
    gameState = 2
  else:
    gameState = 3
  return(gameState)

print(gameCraps(crapsRoll))
```

this doesnt confuse the roll function with the result from the roll and it doesnt re roll for each condition check.